# How to convert UTC time to PST?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table has date column in UTC time zone. I want to convert the data into PST. How to do this?

UTC time:

| date |
| --- |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:47.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:28:04.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:45.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:27.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:27.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |
| 2017-06-26 17:35:51.0 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For table `test_table` with column `date_column` containing datetime, to get local time from UTC you can use:

```
SELECT datetime(date_column,'localtime') as local_time from test_table;
```

Example with IST (UTC is 5 hours and 30 minutes behind of IST):

```
SELECT datetime(date_column||"-05:30") as local_time from test_table;
```

Comment: I thought that || is used for string concatenation not for date time arithmetic. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works on date column without timezone information, using concatenation to add timezone offset. Once timezone offset is added SQLite automatically takes care of conversion.

To have the timezone conversion predictable from UTC to your target timezone offset, you can use `datetime` as follows:

```
select datetime('2022-10-10', "-08:00")
select datetime('2022-10-10T09:02', "-08:00")
select datetime('2022-10-10 09:02', "-08:00")
select datetime('2021-08-16T09:02:44+00:00', "-08:00") // if there was something else like +01:30 it will handle it accordingly
```

It should work with any valid date format. For any date value without timezone offset it will automatically consider to be converting from UTC.